# Celery + 2 redis: broker and cache

Tags: redis, celery

What I have:
1) redis on standart port - this is cache
2) redis on port 53333 - this is a broker

Why celery get task successfully, but don't return it to port 53333? This task I can see by redis-cli on standart port.
Can you help me to correct 'celeryconfig.py'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for trouble... Follow string inserted to 'celeryconfig.py':

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "redis" 
CELERY_REDIS_HOST = "localhost" 
CELERY_REDIS_PORT = 56379
```

...and all working.